# Home Assistant OS and nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, home-server, reverse-proxy

I have installed official KVM installation of Home Assistant on a linux host machine.
The host machine is 192.168.0.110 and the KVM Home Assistant on that host machine is 192.168.0.73:8123.

I wanna a SSL/HTTPS connection for the Home Assistant. I have a domain and I have certificates on my host machine for it (Let's Encrypt via Certbot).

Then I created a nginx reverse proxy on the host machine. Of course the port 80 and 443 is forwarded in my router to the 192.168.0.110 (the host machine).

```
server { if ($host = domain.xyz) { return 301
https://$host$request_uri; }

 listen 80;  server_name domain.xyz;  return 301
https://$host$request_uri; }

server { listen 443 ssl; server_name domain.xyz;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.xyz/privkey.pem;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.73:8123;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  } }
```

When I go to 192.168.0.73:8123, everything works normally, but when I go to `https://domain.xyz` it throws a 502 Bad Gateway.

Can you please help me with that? I am looking at the reverse proxy and I see no mistake here?

```
NGINX ERROR LOG:
[error] 1584367#1584367: *72 connect() failed (113: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: MY_IP, server: DOMAIN.XYZ, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "192.168.0.73:8123", host: "DOMAIN.XYZ"
```

Comment: `when I got to https://domain.xyz` from within your network? Do you also have NAT hairpinning enabled for those port redirects? I take it your domain.xyz points to the correct public IP, and this IP is not a CG-NAT IP

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborateo mroe? I do not understand.

Comment: which part? port forwarding? NAT hairpinning? CG-NAT? DNS?

Comment: NAT hairpinning, CG-NAT. Port 80, 443 is forwarded to the host machine where nginx is running. I have running few websites on these ports without problem.

Comment: Oh, OK, then don't worry about NAT hairpinning or CG-NAT - you probably have the former, and are not hamstrung by the latter

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with this part of your Nginx config file :

```
server { if ($host = domain.xyz) { return 301
https://$host$request_uri; }
```

I don't understand why you perform a redirection (301) on the domain itself. It generates a loop.

I'm not a Nginx expert but, for me that means that if I arrive on `https://domain.xyz`, I'm redirected to `https://domain.xyz` and so on...

Try to remove this part and check if it's better.

Comment: It is ike when you write the domain.xyz so normally it will go http:// so it will redirect you to the https:// of that domain, anyway I've tried it and still not working.

Comment: Is everything ok with the Nginx service ? Do you have an error when you restart the service ? - Can you check if `domain.xyz` is correctly resolve with DNS (The A record) ?

Comment: Nginx is OK, no errors when running the test command or restarting. Domain is reportinng correctly my IP adress (the A record).

Comment: Is the part `# WebSocket support` useful / mandatory ? I mean, when I have an issue like this, I try to remove the more thing as possible to eliminate guesswork. - Maybe try to create a basic proxy by following this : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: When I do only like this: 
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.xyz;
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.73:8123;
        }
}
and I go to http://domain.xyz it is showing me different website that is running on that nginx server.

Comment: Ok so you probably have another server definition on your Nginx configuration that takes the lead. Maybe a  `default_server`. You can check with this command : `grep -R default_server /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Try to put : `listen 80 default_server;` on the server block you want to be access by default.
You have in Nginx (like Apache) an option called `server_name`. You can put it inside your server block like : `server_name  domain.xyz;`

Comment: No I have no default settings and that website where it went also have server_name set correctly. So the grep command do not find anything.